# How to create a new canvas on JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jpanel

i'm making an MSPaint like application on java, but i'm stuck on create a new canvas (a white background JPanel)

My Code is this:

```
public void creaLienzo(){
        BufferedImage canvas=new BufferedImage(lienzo.getWidth(),
                lienzo.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2=canvas.createGraphics();
        g2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        lienzo.paint(g2);
    }
```

But the JPanel doesn't draw the white background.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Setting the background would Not be the way to do this.

Since you would only want this once, use:

```
g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have a separate panel for the canvas you could do this.

```
 public void addNew(JPanel panel)
 {
   panel.removeAll();
   panel.add(new Canvas());
 }
```

you can set the background color for a jPanel by using

```
jPanelName.setBackground(Color.white);
```